# No members argc and argv in QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get an old (2013) QT application building, but I'm running into this compilation error when running the Makefile:

```
applicationtrayicon.cpp:222:39: error: no member named 'argc' in 'QApplication'
    for (int i = 0; i < QApplication::argc(); i++)
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
applicationtrayicon.cpp:224:31: error: no member named 'argv' in 'QApplication'
        args << QApplication::argv()[i];
```

It appears to be caused by this function:

```
void ApplicationTrayIcon::activateApplication()
{
    setApplicationEnable(true);
    window_->authenticateAndShow();

    OnChangeConnectedState(true);
    login_indicator_->setIconVisibleInMenu(false);

    // Check run args
    QStringList args;

    for (int i = 0; i < QApplication::argc(); i++)
    {
        args << QApplication::argv()[i];
    }

    this->recivedCommandLine(args);

    // Check delayed query - from drag and drop
    if (!filesQuery_.isEmpty())
    {
        window_->handleCtxMenuCommands(MainWindow::APPLICATION_CHOICE, filesQuery_);
        filesQuery_.clear();
    }
}
```

The original developers are unavailable for question, and I'm not finding anything about these methods (`QApplication::argc` and `QApplication::argv`) with google.

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you aware of the widely used prototype for main(), with two parameters called "argc" and "argv" ?

Comment: Use some recent Qt5 version and port your old application to Qt5. Read carefully the documentation of [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html)

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm aware of those. I'm unsure if `QApplication::argv` and `QApplication::argc` are just another way to access the traditional `argc` and `argv` values or if `QApplication` is doing something to them. It's hard to know if I can't find documentation on these functions.

Comment: Just build the application against the appropriate version of Qt. It's very unlikely you will be able to port it to newer version of Qt unless it's very small...

Comment: @Jaa-c I'm not sure what the original version used to develop this app is. And the [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/) appears to only show the latest 3 versions, so I would rather upgrade the app than be stuck dealing with undocumented deprecated code.

Comment: @SimpleJ: Depends on how big the application is. It could take some serious effort. Old docs is here: http://doc.qt.io/archives/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That methods are gone, you need to use [QStringList QCoreApplication::arguments()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments) instead:

> Returns the list of command-line arguments.

So just replace these lines:

```
// Check run args
QStringList args;

for (int i = 0; i < QApplication::argc(); i++)
{
    args << QApplication::argv()[i];
}

this->recivedCommandLine(args);
```

with this one line:

```
this->recivedCommandLine(QApplication::arguments());
```